# How to transform input data with NestJS and TypeORM

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I want to create functionality where I can transform incoming data before it hits the database. Let's say that we want to make sure that when a new user is created, the firstName and lastName attribute values are always starting with a capital letter. Or another great example is to prevent login issues and store email addresses always in lowercase letters.

I've taken a look at the pipe documentation of NestJS but it's too generic. I want to be able to specify which fields need transformation and I don't want to create a pipe for each attribute or endpoint that needs transformation.

I've also tried the @Transform decorator form the 'class-transformer' package but this doesn't seem to work.

```
export class UserRoleCreateDto {
  @IsDefined()
  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @Transform((name) => name.toUpperCase())
  readonly name;
}
```

The expected result should be the name in uppercase letters but it's not.

Anyone any ideas or examples on how to implement proper input transformation for NestJS / TypeORM before it hits the database?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also use TypeORM's entity listeners.

## @BeforeInsert

You can define a method with any name in entity and mark it with @BeforeInsert and TypeORM will call it before the entity is inserted using repository/manager save.

```js
@Entity()
export class User {
    
    @BeforeInsert()
    nameToUpperCase() {
        this.email = this.email.toLowerCase()
        this.name = this.name.toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

Source [here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/listeners-and-subscribers.md)

Answer (score 17):

Here is a small working example

```
  @UsePipes(new ValidationPipe({transform: true}))
  @Get('test_input')
  async testInput(@Query() data: UserRoleCreateDto): Promise<any> {

    return data;
  }
```

and checking in bash:

```
curl 'http://localhost:3060/test_input?name=hello'

{"name":"HELLO"}
```

Check that you have `ValidationPipe` decorator and especially `transform: true` option, without these it doesn't work. `transform: true` automatically transforms input data to the class instance.

More about validation on the nestjs documentation page - [link](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation)

Also, just in case, instead of `@Query()` decorator you can use `@Body()` for POST data or `@Param()` for URL parameters

Comment: This only works when the value is being processed by the controllers middlewares. It doesn't work if the program is running from a script, cron job, etc.

Answer (score 7):

This is what you need:

```
class ClassName {
  @Transform((param) => param.value.toUpperCase())
  name: string;
}
```

Note that the destructured object in the transform won't care about property name. these are things that you can use in `param`: `value, key, obj, type`

[ref read more](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer#advanced-usage)

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to use it is
**`@Transform(({name}) => name.toUpperCase())`**
and not
`@Transform((name) => name.toUpperCase())`

**Without the `{}`, the value is transformed into an object**... I found out by adding a `console.log()` inside the `Transform()` when my `@Matches()` validator was throwing an error.

Looks like it's caused by a breaking change in the lib `'class-transformer'` as mentionned in this issue : [transforming string to lowercase turns string into object [...]](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer/issues/560)

> Guys this is because breaking changes in patch version.

Top voted answer's advice is adding `@UsePipes(new ValidationPipe({transform: true}))` but it changed nothing for me (However, I may already have `app.useGlobalPipes`)